# Topology generated by a family of maps and a similar question for measure theory

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory

Let us say that $X$ is a set, $f$ from $X$ to some topological space $Y$, and we endow it with the smallest topology for which $f$ is continuous.  Is it true that for any $f_1:X \rightarrow V$ with $V$ some topological space that is continuous wrt this topology must be $f_1=k\circ f$?  What if $V$ is $\mathbb{R}$?  Not in general.  The embedding of $\mathbb{R}$ into the unit circle shows a counterexample to the topological version.  What does $Y$ have to be to make it true?  The condition on $Y$ may depend on $X$ (Presumably the only thing mattering being the cardinality of $X$) or it may be universal.  I don't know.

This is intended to be similar to the fact that if $g$ is a measurable map from a set $Z$ into $\mathbb{R}$ wrt the sigma algebra generated by $h$ then $g=k\circ h$.  Can something like this also be obtained when we replace $\mathbb{R}$ with other measurable spaces?  I am unsure about the extension because the proof here uses indicator functions which work only for $\mathbb{R}$ as the codomain.

Comment: could you explain what is $k$?

Comment: A continuous map with codomain $V$ and domain $Y$.

Comment: The universal property is the other way round then. That is, for maps _into_ $X$, not from.

Comment: I believe you are putting the initial topology on $X$, which has the universal property with respect to maps _into_ $X$, not maps _from_ $X$ into another space. No?

Comment: No.  I'm talking about the topology generated by one function $f$ on $X$, which comes initially as just a set.  I want then to see if every map cts wrt this topology is actually cts because it factors through this $f$.

Comment: I'm trying to say that this is called the initial topology on $X$ with respect to the map $f\colon X\to Y$, and by construction it has the universal property that every map $g\colon Z\to X$ is continuous if and only if the composition $f\circ g\colon Z\to Y$ is continuous. On a second thought, maybe you are interested in something else.